# PLC Programming Best Practices

Tags: plc

I have recently inherited a PLC project. We are using Automation Direct PLCs and using the C-more software for writing ladder logic.

C-more allows me to add rungs for "Execute on every scan", "Execute when called", etc.

It also allows me to break out separate sections under each of these headings to attempt some organization.

Are there some agreed upon best practices for structuring ladder logic programs? I'm trying to bring some sanity to the development process.

Comment: Standardizing some of the "best practices" of ladder logic was the reason for creating this [Patterns of Ladder Logic Programming](http://www.contactandcoil.com/patterns-of-ladder-logic-programming/) page (disclaimer - it's something I wrote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no established norms in the PLC programming realm, I've been developing, commissioning, maintaining (and reverse-engineering) PLC programs for 26 years.  Many organizations develop in-house standards, but there are no accepted industry-wide standards.  However, a method I gleaned from an old pro dictates placing decision-making rungs first (evaluating conditions and setting flags), making control decisions in the next segment, turning outputs on/off in the next section, and monitoring performance/upset conditions in the last.

It's based on how older machines evaluated I/O and handled ladder execution.  The advent of ladder 'sub-routines' has helped enormously; I generally treat each motor as a 'sub-system' element and assign its' own sub-routine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Document as you go.  Logic, elements, memory map, etc.  Document for "the other person", even if that person is YOU.  PLCs and their programs tend to have a LONG life, so you will be glad 1 year, 5 years or even 20 years down the road when you have to tweak/debug that PLC.  You'll be glad you explained things in a little more detail by documenting it for "the other person".

Do NOT wait until "the end" to document.  Yes, that implies that you need to keep the documentation up-to-date.

Comment: I was hoping for someone to chime in with an opinion about how best to structure the actual ladder logic program(best practices, organization, etc.) You're right, I'll have to meticulously document and impose some structure that makes sense since as far as I can tell people in the PLC community don't seem to worry too much about this sort of thing

Comment: @dacox - give people time - the PLC tag isn't the most popular, but people do show up from time to time.  I have a few that I use, but I do not program PLCs professionally.  You may want to post this same question on Automation Direct's forum - you may get some good nuggets that are specific to their PLC line.

Comment: Not specific to PLCs but an excellent answer for ALL development. Document as you go and keep it up to date. (Even a GOOD weekend can make you forget where you were going with something - having nearly finished a really clever chunk of code on a Friday and then trying to finish it with a hangover on Monday and you didn't put a routemap at the top is the pits.  It is a bit like a maths exam - 70% for picking a valid approach 30% for actually doing it correctly.